# Mysql query to get count from records not containing exact value

Tags: mysql

Suppose I have this table:

```
id       |     name      |      date
1               aaa               11
2               aaa|bbb           11
3               bbb|ccc           11
4               aaa|ccc           11
1               aaaX              12
2               aaaX|bbbY         12
3               bbbY|cccY         12
4               aaaZ|cccZ         12
```

Expected Data:

```
date : 11,    name: aaa,    count: 3
date : 11,    name: bbb,    count: 1
date : 11,    name: ccc,    count: 2
date : 12,    name: aaa,    count: 3
date : 12,    name: bbb,    count: 2
date : 12,    name: ccc,    count: 2
```

I want to fetch the count of the names grouping by date.
I have tried with this query:

```
SELECT name, COUNT(*) AS count
FROM mytable
WHERE name LIKE "%aaa%" OR
name LIKE "%bbb%" OR
name LIKE "%ccc%"
GROUP BY name
```

result that I am getting is for names aaa,bbb,ccc,aaa|bbb, aaa|ccc, aaaX|bbbY,...

What will be the query to get this ?

Comment: The query, or the solution? The solution is to normalize your schema.

Comment: still using "CVS" (Comma separated values) in 2018? You should normalize your data.. Then you won't have the trouble of writing a number generator and to use `SUBSTRING_INDEX()` to split the column name

Comment: whats your advice? can u please comment on that

Comment: the data that is stored in the name column, that is dynamic. how can I normalize it?